# How to make django to save user password in plain-text?

Tags: django

Ok..

First, I know all the consequences of using plain-text.

But, how to make django to save user password in plain-text?

Comment: Create your own [custom password hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/) that just passes the input through to the output.

Comment: Dude are you serous??? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give up to use in plaintext... and I use MD5 password hasher.. but in Django, the default MD5 password hasher use a SALT to make the hash, and in delphi we can't use them.. the solution is use this:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.UnsaltedMD5PasswordHasher',
)
```

Use in setting.py, and recreate all users. After that, all passwords is stored in MD5 pure, and we can read in Delphi or other software.